# C# ADO Parameterized Update Query fails to update because of DBNull

Tags: c#, .net, ado

I've spent all day on this and can't seem to find a solution. I added parameters @dMCA and @dMOCP to an already working update query. These values can be null so I test for that and write DBnull if they are in-fact null. Ever since adding these the query has no effect any more. The query does not error out via the "catch".
It's odd because I was not having any issues with @cirID whose value can also be null.

Everyone I look, included the AI tools, all say what I am doing is correct.

How do I troubleshoot this. Im not sure where to go from here? This is my first .Net program. Months after thinking this project was done I found out that this update query is not working. Now I am in panic mode and dont know if I can trust any of my queries. If they are not throwing errors and falling into the "catch" how am I supposed to catch design flaws like this.

Please help me learn. Thank you to all.

The SQL update that has no effect:

```
        static void UpdateDM_Equip(DMMotor motor, string DBLocation)
    {
        var conString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + DBLocation;
        var SQLString = "UPDATE tblEquL set EQU_CALLOUT = @name, ixCircuit1 = @cirID, LT_CON_1 = @KVA, LT_HP_1 = @HP, LT_CAL_1 = @NEC , LT_FAC_1 = @factor , D_NOTE = @note1, R_NOTE = @note2, dMCA = @MCA, dMOCP = @MOCP WHERE ixEquL = @ID";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conString)) //create a connection
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQLString, connection); //create a command and set its connection
            try
            {
                connection.Open(); //open connection
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", motor.EQU_CALLOUT); //add the safe parameter
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cirID", motor.ixCircuit1.HasValue ? motor.ixCircuit1.Value : DBNull.Value); //add the safe parameter
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KVA", motor.LT_CON_1); //add the safe parameter
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HP", motor.LT_HP_1); //add the safe parameter
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NEC", motor.LT_CAL_1); //add the safe parameter
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@factor", motor.LT_FAC_1); //add the safe parameter
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note1", motor.D_NOTE); //add the safe parameter
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note2", motor.R_NOTE); //add the safe parameter
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", motor.ixEquL); //add the safe parameter
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MCA", motor.dMCA.HasValue ? motor.dMCA.Value : DBNull.Value); //add the safe parameter
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MOCP", motor.dMOCP.HasValue ? motor.dMOCP.Value : DBNull.Value); //add the safe parameter
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Debug.WriteLine("Command Text: " + cmd.CommandText);
            }//end of try
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("UpdateDM_Equip error: " + ex.Message);
                foreach (OleDbParameter parameter in cmd.Parameters)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(parameter.ParameterName + ": " + (parameter.Value ?? "NULL"));
                }
            } //end of catch
        }//end of using. Automatically closes connections
    }
```

The class definition used within the SQL update (for reference):

```
    class DMMotor
{
    //init fields/members - TODO review how we are handling several of these fields that determine load type and thus NEC demand factor.
    public int ixEquL; //Access table primary Key
    public string EQU_CALLOUT = "";
    public string Distribution_Equip; //Non-DM variable. Custom for processing conversion of other motor types
    public double bucketSpace = 1; //NON-DM variable. Custom for calcing how much of MMC section motor needs.
    public int Circuit_ID_TEI_DB; //NON-DM variable. Custom temp store the TEI database circuit_ID (primary Key). Used to determine if equip shares circuit per TEI DB V21C+ assignment.
    public double Circuit_KVA_con_TEI_DB; //NON-DM variable. Custom temp store TEI DB circuits connected KVA
    public double Circuit_FLA_con_TEI_DB; //NON-DM variable. Custom temp store TEI DB circuits connected FLA
    public double Circuit_KVA_op_TEI_DB; //NON-DM variable. Custom temp store TEI DB circuits Operating KVA
    public int iID = 0;
    public int? ixCircuit1; //holds the circuit assignment relation - Could be null
    public int ixEquSGroup;
    public int ixDwgEqu;
    public int iCircuitPhase = 1; //default value when you manually create equipment without dist assign.
    public int ixLayerSystem = 1;
    public int iBreakerSize = 3; //cloest field to determining Phase. 2nd closest is V_P_W. I will use this in UpdateDM_Circuit
    public int? BreakerKey; //NON_DM variable. Custom field to store the tblbreaker key for a breaker size that is read in from tbl Electrical_Circuits
    public int BreakerAmps; //NON_DM variable. Custom field to store breaker size in amps before determing the breaker key and populating DMMotor.BreakerKey
    public int iBreakerWire = 1;
    public bool bInsertedOnDrawing = false;
    public bool bShowOnOneLine = true; //bool to show on SL
    public bool bShowInSchedule = true;
    public bool bShowFeederID = true;
    public int iDwgOneLineBranch = -3; //typically negative. Default = 0 in DM
    public int ixDwgOneLineBranch = 1; //int ref to tblDwgOneLineBranch. Block rep for equipment on SL.
    public int iDwgOneLineWireDisconnect = -2; //typically negative. Default = 0 in DM
    public int ixDwgOneLineWireDisconnect = 2; //int ref to tblDwgOneLineWire. Type of disc on SL
    public int iDwgOneLineWireBreaker = -2; //typically negative. Default = 0 in DM
    public int ixDwgOneLineWireBreaker = 6;  //int ref to tblDwgOneLineWire. Block rep for OCP on SL
    //public int iDwgOneLine = 0; //--THIS IS NOT A PARAMETER IN THE DB--
    public string V_P_W; //TODO this eval'd to Null on a test read
    public string voltage_Parsed; //NON-DM variable. custom field. Not in DM. Truncate the "3P 4W", Leave just "208Y/120V"
    public string LOAD_DES; //this is what gets reported in pnl schedule
    public int GND = 1;
    public int ISO_GND = 0;
    public string LT_DESC_1 = "Motor"; //TODO read this instead
    public double LT_CON_1; //KVA
    public string LT_HP_1; //motor size in HP. Chg'd to string to handle "F".
    public double LT_CAL_1; //NEC connected KVA
    public double LT_FAC_1 = 1; //Connected load multiplier (IE: 1.25 for motor)
    public string LT_DESC_2 = "Motor";
    public double LT_CON_2 = 0;
    public double LT_CAL_2 = 0;
    public int LT_FAC_2 = 1;
    public string LT_DESC_3 = "Motor";
    public double LT_CON_3 = 0;
    public double LT_CAL_3 = 0;
    public int LT_FAC_3 = 1;
    public string LT_DESC_4 = "Motor";
    public double LT_CON_4 = 0;
    public double LT_CAL_4 = 0;
    public int LT_FAC_4 = 1;
    public int Dx = 0;
    public int Dy = 0;
    public int Dz = 0;
    public int dRotation = 0;
    public int d3DAngle = 0;
    public int d3DDistance = 0;
    public int d3DAngleDisconnect = 0;
    public int d3DDistanceDisconnect = 0;
    public int dDiscZ = 0;
    public int iDiscZ_custom = 0;
    public double? dMCA; //is null if not overriden
    public double? dMOCP; //is null if not overriden
    public int FAULT_PN = 0;
    public int dFaultTotalMotor = 0;
    public string D_NOTE; //"Drawing Note 1" - will populate with ID = Primary Key for tracking
    public string R_NOTE = "NO DESCRIPTION"; //"Drawing Note 2" - will populate with load description for tracking
    public string AIC = "Verify w/ Single Line";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an OleDb parameterized query it is of uttermost importance to add the parameters in the same order in which they appear in your query text. OleDb doesn't resolve the parameters using their names. It uses the parameter position in the Parameters collection. Your ID parameter is not in the proper position to be used in the WHERE statement

So to fix your problem just move the parameter @ID after the two new parameters

```
....
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MCA", motor.dMCA.HasValue ? motor.dMCA.Value : DBNull.Value); //add the safe parameter
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MOCP", motor.dMOCP.HasValue ? motor.dMOCP.Value : DBNull.Value); //add the safe parameter
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", motor.ixEquL);
```